# How to get void.class in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

In order to use MethodHandle's, i need to represent a no-return-type: void. In java it's as simple as `void.class`(yes, it works), in scala you can get `int.class` by using

```
scala> classOf[Int]
res1: Class[Int] = int
```

, but by using `classOf[Void]`, you get

```
scala> val t = classOf[Void]
t: Class[Void] = class java.lang.Void

scala> t.isPrimitive
res4: Boolean = false
```

which isn't obviously `void.class`.

Comment: I don't know anything about Scala, but how about `classOf[void]`?

Comment: @tbodt That does not work, `void` does not exist in Scala.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scala> classOf[Unit]
res0: Class[Unit] = void
```

Answer (score 4):

See Andrew Jones' answer about return types in Scala. If you still need it though:

```
scala> val c = java.lang.Void.TYPE
c: Class[Void] = void

scala> c.isPrimitive
res0: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
classOf[Void]
```

, use:

```
Void.TYPE
```

REPL Output:

```
scala> classOf[Void]
res14: Class[Void] = class java.lang.Void

scala> Void.TYPE
res15: Class[Void] = void
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a void type in Scala. All functions return some value. If the value isn't explicitly defined, it is type `Unit`.

Further, `void` is considered a pseudo-type by Java. Because of this, there is no way for void to be the type of a return object.